# How to get warnings in VS Code when I have duplicate property keys in a JS object literal?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, duplicates

For example, a have an object:

let obj = {
            prop: test,
            prop: test1,
        };

And I want to get warning on a second "prop".

Comment: Add ESLint to your project. You can get more information from here https://eslint.org/

Answer (score 3):

By default, VS Code's JavaScript support only checks the syntax code. You can opt into semantic checking as well by adding a `// @ts-check` comment to the top of your file:

[image: TS check reporting duplicate keys]

TS check can catch many more errors than just duplicated keys. [More info about ts-check](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

If you use ESLint and make sure the [no-dupe-keys](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-dupe-keys) rule is enabled, it'll show a warning when you have code like that.

ESLint can be integrated into VSCode with [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint).